# Crystal Reports: Suppress records when any value from column #1 match any value from column #2

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a Crystal Report, pulling data from 2 different databases.  The first database contains most of the customer data and looks something like this:

```
Customer ID  Name    ZIP
11111        John    10101
22222        Mary    10102
33333        Jeff    10203
```

The second database just pulls one column, the customer ID that can be linked back to the original database:

```
Customer ID
11111
44444
55555
```

I want to only show the records where any customer IDs in database 1 do not match any customer IDs in database 2.  If any of them match, I want that row suppressed.  I have tried several things, but I seem to get all records returned, or none. So in this case I would get this ideally:

```
Customer ID  Name    ZIP
22222        Mary    10102
33333        Jeff    10203
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a formula called suppress

```
if {database1.Customer_ID} = {database2.Customer_ID} then 1 else 0
```

Then in your selection criteria use

```
{@suppress} = 0
```

This should suppress all instances where these match as the only accepted value is '0' which the suppress formula sets as a negative match

Comment: K Emery, unfortunately when I use this (I had done something similar before), I get no rows at all.  I don't know if this is relevant, but the customer ID in the first database is an integer data type and the customer ID in the second database was a varchar so I converted the second to an int as well (only numbers appear in these fields).

Comment: @Steven are you actually looking to omit the data all together from the report or 'hide it' so its not visible?

Comment: Just hide it so it's not visible on the report itself.

Comment: Have you tried placing the `{@suppress} = 0` in the details suppress forumula?

Comment: I did try that, but it turned out being the link between the to databases. The joins were wrong on the link so I wasn't getting enough data.  I had to change it to a left outer join and to "enforce to".  Thanks for your help.